# How to handle function that returns a Promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I'm wanting to declare a Promise's resolved value from a library like so.

```
// lib.js
exports.foo = function(){
    return new Promise(..)
}

// main.js
import { foo } from "./lib"

let x = await foo()
```

The await isn't working, and it seems everything I've tried leads to this error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection`

Comment: What's inside the `new Promise`? Also, you can't `await` on the top level (yet)

Comment: @CertainPerformance there's a network request in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below, as CertainPerformance mentioned in the comments, you can't use `await` at the top level yet. Additionally, in order to use `await` you must add the `async` keyword to the function in which you `await` the resolution of a `Promise`.

```
// lib.js
exports.foo = function() {
    return new Promise(..)
};

// main.js
import { foo } from "./lib";

function async main() {
    let x = await foo();
};
```

Comment: or you can use IIFE:


    (async () => { 
        try {
            const x = await foo();
        } catch (err) {
            // handle error
        }
    })(); 


https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression

Answer (score 0):

You simply give the promise constructor a
`function(resolve,reject){
 /* your code here with resolve(value); and reject(error);*/
}` as a parameter then to call it and give the value to `x` you call
 `var x;
 foo().then(function(value){ 
x=value;
} ); //here you can optionally add .catch(function(error){ your error catch imp here}); if you want to catch your error`